# JavaScript & Регулярные выражения: обнаружение двух повторений с помощью String:search

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Хотим обраружить `<br/>`, повторяющийся один раз:

```
let string = '<p>Рыба<br/><br/>Мясо</p>';
console.log(string.search(/<br[\/]>{1}/));
```

Результат: `7`. Пока всё нормально.

Теперь хотим обраружить `<br/>`, повторяющийся два раза:

```
let string = '<p>Рыба<br/><br/><br/>Мясо</p>';
console.log(string.search(/<br[\/]>{2}/));
```

Результат: `-1`.

В чём ошибка использования квантификатора точного количества повторений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярное выражение `/<br[\/]>{1}/` ищет подстроку `<br/` и *ровно один символ `>`*, так как квантификатор определяет количество совпадений подшаблона (по-английски используется термин *atom*), находящегося слева от него. Каждый отдельно взятый символ является таким "атомом", а также группы (подмаски), символьные классы.

Чтобы квантифицировать *последовательность* символов/"атомов", необходимо использовать группировочную конструкцию: *захватывающую* или *незахватывающую группу/подмаску*.

Так как повторяющиеся захватывающие группы сохраняют в буфере только последнее захваченное значение, их использование имеет смысл только для читабельности регулярного выражения. Логичнее и эффективнее в таких случаях использовать *незахватывающую группу*:

```
/(?:<br\/>){2}/
 ^^^      ^
```

`(?:...)` и есть пример такой группы.

```js
var s = '<p>Рыба<br/><br/><br/>Мясо</p>';
console.log(s.search(/(?:<br\/>){2}/));
```

Comment: Очень хорошее объяснение! Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Comment: Не за что, вот ещё ссылка на демо [`(?:<br\/>){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/Bu6SKx/1). К сожалению, объяснение шаблона только на английском.

Answer (score 1):

Группу объявите для повтора

```js
let string = '<p>Рыба<br/><br/><br/>Мясо</p>';
console.log(string.search(/(<br\/>){2}/));
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Скажите, а как мезанизм регулярных выражений работал до этого (в коде из вопроса)? По моему эксперименту не скажешь, что всё очевидно...

Comment: До этого проверка повтора действовала только на `>`.